# "unscoped" variable in react class module file

Tags: reactjs, scope, es6-modules

I have a component that receives some props. In the same file, I have some helper functions that also use one of the props. I'd like to save the prop value inside a variable in the file.

Is there any reason in terms of functionality or style that I should not do this?

Here's some pseudo code to show what I'm talking about, representing the whole file:

```
// imports go here

let unscopedVar = null

const myOnBlur = (ev) => {
    console.log(unscopedVar)
    console.log(ev)
}

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    unscopedVar = props.someVar

    return <input onBlur={myOnBlur} />
}

export default MyComponent
```

The alternative would be to pass more variables to the functions, but I'd like to avoid that. In my real code, more than one function needs the variable, and they each take more than one other parameter:

```
// imports...

const myOnBlur = (ev, unscopedVar) => {
    console.log(unscopedVar)
    console.log(ev)
}

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    return <input onBlur = {(ev) => myOnBlur(ev, props.someVar)}
}
```

Comment: You should generally be relying on `getState`/`setState` for state management unless you're using a dedicated state store like Redux. So no, what you have above isn't a recommended practice. As a side note, you can't assign to a `const` variable after it's created.

Comment: @JLRishe I don't think this is related to state, if it is please explain. The variable will be updated only when the component receives new props. You're right about the `const` and I've fixed that, thank you

Comment: _"The variable will be updated only when the component receives new props."_ Sounds like you're using it to store state values and just not calling it "state". As for why you shouldn't do this, for one thing, if you had multiple instances of that component, they would all be sharing the same variable and overwriting each other's values.

Comment: @JLRishe thank you for your input. I've edited the question to clarify why I want to do this. If I understand you correctly, you're saying that the `unscopedVar` should be in MyComponent's state, and the myOnBlur function should be a class method of MyComponent?

Comment: What is it you are wanting to achieve? I don't understand what you are doing with the property?

Comment: @TimBJames I want to "globally" store a variable that I need to use in multiple helper functions, without passing it to each helper function individually

Comment: @KWeiss You have a bunch of options: (1) Pass in the variable using a lambda function, like in your second example (2) Make your component a class and make myOnBlur a method, then it can use this.props to access props (3) Declare your `myOnBlur` function inside the `MyComponent` function; then it has access to the `props` parameter.

Comment: @KWeiss Have you considered sticking it into LocalStorage if it is being used in multiple helper functions?

Comment: @JLRishe that last comment answers my question, if you could put it and the "multiple instances of the component" concern into an answer, that would be great!

Comment: @JLRishe Missed some of these comments. If you guys want to go ahead with another answer that's fine by me, otherwise I can put a remark about multiple instances in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the biggest problem with that approach is that there will only ever be one instance of that variable. If there are multiple instances of your component, then they will all be fighting over the value of that variable and messing up each others' data.

So generally you shouldn't try to store values outside of your components.

In terms of alternatives, there are several ways you could go about it:

1. The approach you described - use a closure to capture the value when the handler is invoked:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    return <input onBlur = {(ev) => myOnBlur(ev, props.someVar)}
}
```

2. Use a class component, in which case the handler can just access `this.props`:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    myOnBlur(ev) {
        console.log(this.props.someVar)
        console.log(ev)
    }

    render() {
        return <input onBlur={this.myOnBlur} />
    }
}
```

3. Define your handler inside the `MyComponent` function, so that it has access to the same scope:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const myOnBlur = (ev) => {
        console.log(props.someVar)
        console.log(ev)
    }

    return <input onBlur={myOnBlur} />
};
```

If your handler is fairly large and complex, the last option is probably the least ideal because it means a separate copy of the whole handler would be created every time the component is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea. Your `unscopedVar` may be equal to `props.someVar` but this is not clear when looking at it's declaration or use. For a toy example it seems harmless, but as your component grows (as they usually do,) it will be harder to keep track of these relations between props and variables.

Another problem arises if you convert your functional component to a class component, after which you'll need to use lifecycle methods to keep the variable in sync with the prop.

If a lot of helper functions use props, you can just use a class component, and access `this.props` in the helper functions:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  myOnBlur = (ev) => {
    console.log(this.props.someVar)
    console.log(ev)
  }

  render() {
    return <input onBlur={this.myOnBlur} />
  }
}
```